# iOS App Orientation issues - switching a project from portrait to landscape

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6

I've been banging my head against the wall for about two weeks now.  I started out on a project that was originally going to be Portrait on the iPhone and iPad.  Somewhere along the line, the project switched to being Landscape on the iPhone and then Landscape on the iPad.

By the way, the app isn't supposed to support rotation, I want this to be Landscape only.  Which by the way, works great on the iPhone and also the iPad Simulator (both iOS 5 and 6).

On the iPad, it's a completely different story.  The Main View Controller is loaded via an xib (just like on the iPhone) and it is set to LANDSCAPE orientation.  I load and run the app on the simulator and everything works GREAT.  I run the app on the iPad and it is launching in portrait mode.  The xib (since it is landscape), just winds up getting drawn on screen in the upper left corner and gets pushed right off the edge.

I have set the Simulated Metrics to Landscape on the main view controller, and the it is set to 1024x768.  I have set the supported orientations to Landscape Left & Landscape Right Only.  I have set the Initial Interface Orientation to Landscape (left home button). I have implemented `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` (returning only `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft`) (by the way, based on NSLog that function is never being called).  I have implemented `supportedInterfaceOrientation` (returning `UIInterfaceMaskOrientationLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight`) (which again, based on `NSLog` is never being called either).

I'm at my wits end.  I'm half tempted just to start the project with a clean slate and take the time to put everything back together.

There has to be something I'm missing, right?

Comment: Your question missed implementing shouldAutorotate which would be called first in iOS6

Comment: I have implemented shoudAutorotate  I am not seeing it get called either.

Comment: are you using navigation controller or tab controller ?

Comment: That's the reason its not getting called. In iOS 6 no more parent controller consult its child for orientation. Try subclassing navigation controller or creating a category for it and override the orientation methods in it. It'll do the magic.

Comment: I subclassed Navigation Controller and overrode the orientation methods on it. I see those methods being called on the iPhone but they are not called on the iPad.

Comment: I guess the orientation support selected in project target is different for iphone and ipad. Just confirm that both are same. And subclass only for iOS 6. For previous versions follow the old shouldrotatetoorientation method.

Comment: shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: correction for previous comment